# Dealing with a dirty table

Tags: python, strings, python-2.x, formatting

I have to deal with a really ugly looking response I get back from a particular device. The string represents a table. Each section of the string represents the form:

```
["id", "date_time", "path", "type","duration","count", "rate"]
```

Which as an example looks like:

```
"1,2014-4-3 10:1:10,somerandompath,some/screwy!stringwithstufflike[0,0,0,0]inIt,0,0;"
```

all table entries as you can see are terminated by `;` and have their elements separated by `,`

But some entries like in `some/screwy!stringwithstufflike[0,0,0,0]inIt` have commas within their data,.. and times/dates `10:1:10` aren't padded with `0`'s to be consistent

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't feel very optimized...

```
def GetEventTable(self):
        # After I split by ',' commas can be inside of [..], 
        # so I combine entries until their number of starting/end braces match
        def split_entry(entry):
            splitentry = entry.split(',')
            for ii in range(len(splitentry))[::-1]:
                start_bracket = splitentry[ii].count('[')
                end_bracket = splitentry[ii].count(']')
                if not start_bracket == end_bracket:
                    splitentry[ii-1:ii+1] = [splitentry[ii-1] + ',' + splitentry[ii]]
            return splitentry
        event_lable = ["id", "date_time", "path", "type","duration","count", "rate"]
        ## This section just talks to the remote device and gets the unformatted string ###
        print "Sending: GET EVENT TABLE"
        stat, raw_data = SendRecieve(self, "GET EVENT TABLE")
        if IsError(stat):
            raise Exception("Error type '{}': {}".format(stat, raw_data))
        print raw_data
        ##################################################################################
        events = raw_data.split(';')[:-1]
        event_table = [{key:value for key,value in zip(event_lable,split_entry(entry) )} for entry in events ]
        return event_table
```

How can I improve the efficiency and also the readability?

It returns a list of dictionaries with keys `["id", "date_time", "path", "type","duration","count", "rate"]`

Comment: Can you add information about how this function is supposed to be used? At the moment, this is just the definition of a function taking no parameter and calling a `SendRecieve` function that probably does not exist on a standard installation (the typo is a pretty good hint).

Comment: @Josay I already explained that I'm getting the data in a string where "entries as you can see are terminated by ; and have their elements separated by ,".. I did however forget to add self :p

Comment: Well then you'll have to excuse me for being a pain but it's quite hard to review anything out of its context (a method out of its class). I'll try to give it a try if no one else has later on.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer**

Because a lot of context is missing, here's the code I will review :

```
def split_entry(entry):
    splitentry = entry.split(',')
    for ii in range(len(splitentry))[::-1]:
        start_bracket = splitentry[ii].count('[')
        end_bracket = splitentry[ii].count(']')
        if not start_bracket == end_bracket:
            splitentry[ii-1:ii+1] = [splitentry[ii-1] + ',' + splitentry[ii]]
    return splitentry

event_lable = ["id", "date_time", "path", "type","duration","count", "rate"]
raw_data = "1,2014-4-3 10:1:10,somerandompath,some/screwy!stringwithstufflike[0,0,0,0]inIt,0,0;"
events = raw_data.split(';')[:-1]
event_table = [{key:value for key,value in zip(event_lable,split_entry(entry) )} for entry in events ]
print event_table
```

---

`ii` is a pretty bad name. `i` is twice shorter and so many times easier to understand.

---

Instead of creating a new list by reversing the return of range, you could just use all the potential of range (or xrange):

---

Instead of using `not A == B`, you could write a more natural `A != B`

---

Looping over an array using `range(len(a))` is an anti-pattern in python. To loop on an array while keeping track of the index, the usual solution is to use `enumerate()`. In your case, because you are updating the array anyway, it is quite tricky to loop on it.

---

Final point : I had trouble understanding your list slicing stuff but as I was messing a bit with it, I obtained a result different from yours ('rate' appears in the final result so it might actually be a good thing) :

```
def split_entry(entry):
    splitentry = entry.split(',')
    for i in xrange(len(splitentry)-1,0,-1):
        chunk = splitentry[i]
        if chunk.count('[') != chunk.count(']'):
                splitentry[i-1] += ',' + chunk
                splitentry[i] = '0'
    return splitentry

event_lable = ["id", "date_time", "path", "type","duration","count", "rate"]
raw_data = "1,2014-4-3 10:1:10,somerandompath,some/screwy!stringwithstufflike[0,0,0,0]inIt,0,0;"
events = raw_data.split(';')[:-1]
event_table = [{key:value for key,value in zip(event_lable,split_entry(entry) )} for entry in events]
print event_table
```

Comment: hmmm.. now that I think of it, I wouldn't need to clear the old value in `splitentry[i] = '0'` seeing as the zip function will only return up to max `len(event_lable)` anyway!